# Writing a Mostly Client-Side App Without Controllers (but still within the Spring framework)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, architecture

We are writing a mostly single-page, client-side app, but server-side/DB endpoints are still required of course, so the natural choice is SpringMVC (since we are a Java / Spring shop).

But this got me thinking why we need the cluttered, very old design for this app:

```
  - Controller layer
  - Service layer
  - DAO layer
```

This app is mostly just the client side making AJAX calls with JSON for DB retrieval/persistence. Do I really need to go thru the Controller layer to receive requests, then invoke a Service method, which in turn invokes a DAO method?

At the same time, I don't want to write a REST Service because it could result in overhead and we may not support all of the REST requirements... but is it the right choice here? If I understand correctly, I would still need a RESTController on the presentation layer?

**My goal is to just directly hit a Service method or, maybe even more directly, a DAO method. Is that how modern apps are written?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot hit a DAO unless you expose it through an API of some sort that can be invoked remotely by the UI application; as a consequence, you need to write a service.

A convenient way of exposing a service is to either:

- Use Spring MVC and use the controllers as stateless endpoints that provide a JSON/Protobuffer/XML sort of payload that is then parsed by your API (with JSON being the simplest option of them all, perhaps) or
- Use Spring Boot, which uses Spring MVC under the hood.

Hope this helps and good luck with your project.